# Is there any way to make sure all the stripes on this linear-gradient are the same size?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am having issues with making all the stripes on this gradient the same size; the one on the bottom is bigger than the rest.

Is there any way to prevent this?

```css
#flag {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;

    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    #6E0E2E,
    #6E0E2E 16%,
    #2A0614 16%,
    #2A0614 32%,
    #BE1864 32%,
    #BE1864 48%,
    #00923C 48%,
    #00923C 64%,
    #1C562E 64%,
    #1C562E 80%,
    #00FECA 80%,
    #00FECA 96%
    );
}
```

```html
<div id="flag"></div> <!-- flag -->
```

Comment: It's the last 4%....if you want them all the same size, you have to pick a size that divides **equally** into 100%. If you want 6 equal stripes they should be 16.66667% EACH ...not 16%

Comment: @Paulie_D so what is not clear in the question considering your close vote? you seems to have the answer :)

Comment: Actually I thought I voted to close as a typo but I can't recall right now if that was the case.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the use of `calc()` to have an accurate result and avoid dealing with float number:

```css
#flag {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    background:
     linear-gradient(180deg, 
       #6E0E2E 0 calc(1*100%/6),
       #2A0614 0 calc(2*100%/6),
       #BE1864 0 calc(3*100%/6),
       #00923C 0 calc(4*100%/6),
       #1C562E 0 calc(5*100%/6),
       #00FECA 0 calc(6*100%/6));

}
```

```html
<div id="flag">
</div> <!-- flag -->
```

You can also do it with multiple background:

```css
#flag {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    background:
     linear-gradient(#6E0E2E 0 0) 0 calc(0*100%/5),
     linear-gradient(#2A0614 0 0) 0 calc(1*100%/5),
     linear-gradient(#BE1864 0 0) 0 calc(2*100%/5),
     linear-gradient(#00923C 0 0) 0 calc(3*100%/5),
     linear-gradient(#1C562E 0 0) 0 calc(4*100%/5),
     linear-gradient(#00FECA 0 0) 0 calc(5*100%/5);
    background-size:100% calc(100%/6);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

```html
<div id="flag">
</div> <!-- flag -->
```