# How to make the blue stripe in the middle thinner than the other 4 stripes?

Tags: html, css

I'm bad at math, so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to change the percentages so that the blue line in the middle is thinner than every other line. Help?

```css
body {
    background:#111;
}


#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    display:grid;
    place-items:center;
}


#flag {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;

    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    #b3106e 20%, /*1st*/
    #b563cf 20% 40%, /*2nd*/
    #4154C0 40% 60%, /*3rd*/
    #3b9cbf 60% 80%, /*4th*/
    #007570 80% 100% /*5th*/
    );
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="flag"></div>

</div> <!-- wrapper -->
</body>
```

Comment: I gave you a way to deal with calc() here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63524596/8620333  you could have easily use it to do what you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nice answer and I've upvoted it, but to be fair its not actually that easy to work out the calculations to change it to have one non-equal row if you're bad at maths (or even if you aren't!)

Comment: @FluffyKitten with calc() you don't need calculation, you only need formula: https://jsfiddle.net/jyc93swp/

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes *I* know that. But if you’re bad at maths then working out what that should be for unequal results is not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on how much thinner you want it!

- The stripes were all evenly distributed at 20% each.
- If you increase this to 21% each, that will give you 100%-(21*4) = 16% for the blue line
- Increase the other lines to 22% each, and you get 100%-(22*4) = 8% for the blue line
- After that, you are getting into decimals.

**How to calculate the line percentages:**

If you want to pick a width for the blue line and calculate what to use for the rest, you can do it like this:

`( 100% - %size of blue line) / 4`

e.g. for a blue line of **6%**: `(100-6)/4` = 23.5% for each of the remaining lines.

**Examples:**

Here it is quite thin at 8%:

```css
body {
    background:#111;
}


#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    display:grid;
    place-items:center;
}


#flag {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;

    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    #b3106e 22%, /*1st*/
    #b563cf 22% 44%, /*2nd*/
    #4154C0 44% 52%, /*3rd*/
    #3b9cbf 52% 76%, /*4th*/
    #007570 76% 100% /*5th*/
    );
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="flag"></div>

</div> <!-- wrapper -->
</body>
```

Or how about 16%:

```css
body {
    background:#111;
}


#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    display:grid;
    place-items:center;
}


#flag {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;

    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    #b3106e 21%, /*1st*/
    #b563cf 21% 42%, /*2nd*/
    #4154C0 42% 58%, /*3rd*/
    #3b9cbf 58% 79%, /*4th*/
    #007570 79% 100% /*5th*/
    );
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="flag"></div>

</div> <!-- wrapper -->
</body>
```

Comment: @ghostyTrickster Glad to help! I've just updated the question with a formula to work backwards, i.e. pick the % size you want the blue line, and you can calculate what %value make the other 4.

Comment: i saw! i should be able to use that to calculate things on my own from now on, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make some math operations, follow these steps:
1- adopt the height that you want for the blue line (in %), for example, 10%
2- now you do 100%-10% = 90%
3- divide the result into the other 4 lines, so 90/4 = 22.5%
4- now your code would be

```
body {
    background:#111;
}


#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    display:grid;
    place-items:center;
}


#flag {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;

    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    #b3106e 22.5%, /*1st - 0 to 22.5*/
    #b563cf 22.5% 45%, /*2nd - 22.5 + 22.5 = 45*/
    #4154C0 45% 55%, /*3rd - 45 + 10 = 55*/
    #3b9cbf 55% 77.5%, /*4th - 55 + 22.5 = 77.5*/
    #007570 77.5% 100% /*5th - 77.5 + 22.5 = 100*/
    );
}
```

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="flag"></div>

</div> <!-- wrapper -->
</body>
```